# dataGridView1.Columns.Clear() throwing IndexOutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have grid with data in it. When moving from view to another view I am clearing existing columns and adding new columns. When executing the line below an `IndexOutOfRange` exception is thrown.

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
```

If `dataGridView1.Columns` is null then I should get NULLReference exception. In the statement I am not indexing into the column collection but only call the `clear()` method. I do not understand why the `IndexOutofRange` exception is thrown.

Another tricky thing here is I modified the code

```
    try
     {
         dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
     }
```

In try block it is throwing exception and in it is coming to Catch block but in catch block the same statement is getting executed without any issue, this is making things even more complex for me to understand the issue.
Please explain why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have any bindings?

Comment: Sorry did not get your question, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: How do you populate the datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should NOT put the code into the catch block - you'll never know which side effects appear! ;-)

Now, I guess this strongly depends on the way the data grid view has been created (automatically, manually) and what is used as datasource (binding source, data table, ...).

You might want to try `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` and then (re-)assign the source again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the question is more about why this happens..i.e how do those moethods work that the exception behaviour could be so complicated.

Comment: yes I have added code in catch block just to what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have any bindings or a DataTable as DataSource... but this could help:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to 
switching gridview properties `AutoGenerateColumns off`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would set up some checkpoints are display what's in them just before you call your code that is throwing the exception.  Are you setting 
`dataGridView1.ColumnCount` somewhere to a number that's bad?  Check the `.Count` also.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to clear the rows of an unbound datagridview

```
datagridview1.Rows.Clear
```

Check if your datagridview is not in edit mode. I solved the problem adding the following line before the rows.clear

```
datagridview1.EndEdit()
```